# How to display lat-lon tick labels with custom boundary shape in Cartopy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, cartopy

Following [this](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/lines_and_polygons/always_circular_stereo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-and-polygons-always-circular-stereo-py) example from Cartopy lets one add a custom shape to a stereographic projection. However, the lat-lon labels with gridlines are not displaying as they're probably cut off by `set_boundary()`. Any way to get around this?

[image]

Minimalistic example code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline # for notebook

map_projection = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=0, )
data_projection = ccrs.PlateCarree()
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5  # by changing radius we can zoom in/out
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpl.path.Path(verts * radius + center)
plot_extent=[-179.9,180, 30, 90]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,6), dpi=100, subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_projection))
ax1.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax1.transAxes)  
ax1.coastlines(linewidths=1.0, color='grey')
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyles='--', color='dimgrey', linewidths=0.8 )
ax1.set_extent(plot_extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),)
gl = ax1.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=1, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', zorder=10)
```

Comment: It seems that the sample in the [official reference](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/lines_and_polygons/always_circular_stereo.html) hides the added shapes when updated to this. `ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True);ax2.gridlines(draw_labels=True)`

Comment: Hi @r-beginners, not sure if I understood you correctly. I described in my question that when using `ax.set_boundary()`, it cuts off the labelled grids. I don't see a way around this in the Colab you shared.

Comment: It was my lack of understanding.

Comment: I get the labels with draw_labels=True in cartopy 0.20.1. However, if I try to customise it with draw_labels={'bottom':'x', 'left':'x'}, the labels don't show. So it doesn't seem to simply be about the boundary cutting labels off.